# Getting LinkedIn Share Stats Of A Page, programmatically

Tags: php, share, linkedin-api

I'm looking for a way to getting linkedin share button stats of a page. 
For example, I'm writing a PHP class, when you use my class on your website like this:

```
include("shareButtonStats.class.php");
$stats = new shareButtonStats;
echo "This page shared " . $stats->show . " times on LinkedIn";
```

As you can see I need to get that page's stats for how many times shared .

As you know when we add LİnkedIn's js file for Share Button ([from here](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-button)), it's including some HTML codes to our page. Something like this :

```
<span class="IN-widget" style="line-height: 1; vertical-align: baseline; display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<span style="padding: 0pt ! important; margin: 0pt ! important; text-indent: 0pt ! important; display: inline-block ! important; vertical-align: baseline ! important; font-size: 1px ! important;">
<span id="li_ui_li_gen_1321370527058_1-container" class="IN-top">
<span id="li_ui_li_gen_1321370527058_1" class="IN-top">   
 .......
```

If I get that HTML codes, without including it to page directly, I can use a RegEx over it, and then get share button count :)

Have you got any idea for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they do and its a simple web page that requires the URL. it returns JSON which either JavaScript or PHP could parse

hope this helps

http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://www.apple.com

Comment: Actually, i looked at LinkedIn API, but i couldn't find share-count method . Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn provides an external API that does just that. Here is how you might use it:

```
function getLinkedInCount($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init("http://www.linkedin.com/cws/share-count?url=" . $url);
    if (is_resource($curl) === true)
    {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.linkedin.com/");

        $result = false;
                $retries = 3;
        while (($result === false) && (--$retries > 0))
        {
            $result = curl_exec($curl);
        }
        curl_close($curl);
    }
    $arr = json_decode(substr($result, 26));
    return $arr->count;
}

echo getLinkedInCount("http://www.google.com/") . "\n";
```

I used cURL for this, however you could use another method of downloading the page.

For a live demo, see: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VDD5aI

Comment: Actually, i looked at LinkedIn API, but i couldn't find share-count method . Thank you !

Comment: Is there any difference between the endpoint you are using and the one documented [here](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/retrieving-share-counts-custom-buttons) ?